# laravel push notification 401 forbidden error

Tags: php, android, laravel, notifications, push

I'm using laravel push notification plugin https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification.
I configured everything as in manual.

But when I try to send message I'm getting all the time:
Sly \ NotificationPusher \ Exception \ PushException
401 Forbidden; Authentication Error

in: /var/www/clients/client0/web5/web/vendor/sly/notification-pusher/src/Sly/NotificationPusher/Adapter/Gcm.php

```
foreach ($tokens as $tokensRange) {
            $message = $this->getServiceMessageFromOrigin($tokensRange, $push->getMessage());

            try {
                $this->response = $client->send($message);
            } catch (ServiceRuntimeException $e) {
                throw new PushException($e->getMessage());
            }
```

In google console the server api is created, ip set to 0.0.0.0/0 (all) in config file I have correct server api key, also tried to give browser api key, but everything is ending with 401.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the app/config/packages/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/config.php? After you run command to publish the config, you need to edit it with your api key.